# Align image inside DIV horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align image inside DIV horizontally and vertically. Problem is that I tried several methods and none of them worked for me.

This is code that I am using:

CSS

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#slika {
float: center;
height: 126px;
width: 111px;
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="slika">
<img src="images/2105602.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="2105602.png">
</div>
```

jsfiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dduygx0x/1/)

Can soemone share his thoughts with me? I can't find solution. It always stays aligned at top.

Comment: Use padding instead of height on the wrapper to keep the image vertically centered. Vertical-align middle is not needed on the img.

Comment: @FunkDoc but if the height of the image changes this could change the size of the box dramatically

Comment: What are the conditions of size for img and the container? dynamic?    defined? ... Here are tons of questions on how to center just search

Comment: @jmore009 that's the problem with his suggestion. Box size is twice larger and there is unwanted white space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3eyfsrc/)**

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#slika {
    height: 126px;
    width: 111px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

Comment: I like this, forgot about the transform properties, still stuck in CSS2!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a margin of 50% and then a top of -(imageheight/2)

```
 img{
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:50%;
    position:relative;
    top:-37px;
}

#slika {
float: left;
height: 126px;
width: 111px;
text-align: center;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dduygx0x/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my soluton for your problem using the common table - table-cell way:

I wrapped you image in a new div:

```
<div id="slika">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
       <img ....>
    </div>
</div>
```

and altered the CSS:

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.img-wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#slika {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 126px;
    width: 111px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
    img{
        max-width:100%;
    }
    
    .img-wrapper{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
        
    #slika {
       border: 1px solid black;
        display: table;
        float: left;
        height: 126px;
        width: 111px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="slika">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://tommyvirtualnikatalog.com.hr/images/akcija/prehrana/2105602.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="2105602.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The benefit of this solution ist that it ist absolut dynamical an can easely made responsive!!

Answer (score 0):

instead of positioning it with hard-coded properties (which would change depending on the image) or using the transform property which wont work in older browsers you can simply wrap the image in a `p` and set the `line-height` to match the height of the box

```
p{
 line-height: 126px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mjdkL6q2/)

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've often used is adding an empty span element next to the image, with

```
#slika span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The idea is that vertical-align is relative to its siblings, therefore a lone element has nothing to work with. The upside of this method is that its completely dynamic, no fixed pixels, works in older environments ( make sure to test that it meets your lowest-end requirements ) and does not affect the container div. The downside would be the extra html.